# How to replace multiple patterns in a single string in Terraform?

Tags: regex, terraform

I am converting Jinja templates to Terraform. I have a variable called `timezone` which has values like this:

regex string- (UTC+01:00) Paris, Bohn, Helsinki, Hungary,Sweden, Austria

```
timezone: {{ WINDOWSTIMEZONE|replace("/","_")|replace("+","_plus_")|replace("(","")|replace(")","")|replace("&","and")|replace(".","")|replace("'","-")|replace(", ","_")|replace(":","_")|replace(" ","_")|lower }}
```

The resultant string in Jinja is
`utc_plus_01_00_paris_bohn_helsinki_hungary_sweden_austria`.

This basically translates to:

```
replace("string","/","-")->resultstring
replace(resultstring,"+","_plus_")
replace(resultstring,"(","")
replace(resultstring,")","")
replace(resultstring,"&","and")
replace(resultstring,".",")
replace(resultstring,"'","-")
replace(resultstring,",","_")
replace(resultstring,":","_")
replace(resultstring," ","_")
finally lower(resultstring)
```

I need to replace timezone based on the above pattern, I am trying to use regex but not able to succeed to write a single expression. How to do this with a single regex expression instead of using multiple replace?

Comment: We need to see the expected result. Also, did you attempt doing a regex replacement in Jinja2? You could convert the Python style regex to a Golang style. Do you also have control over the output of the original string?

Comment: added the expected result

Comment: I do not really see this being possible with a single regex function or method.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct replacement of what you have in Jinja would be nested calls to `replace` where the result of one is the input to the next:

```
replace(
  replace(
    replace(
      # ...
    ),
    ":", "_",
  )
  " ", "_",
)
```

Of course, that's not very readable or maintainable, and Terraform doesn't have anything equivalent to the "filter" syntax that Jinja has for chaining multiple transformations into a linear pipeline.

A different way to think about this problem, since you are only making single-character replacements anyway, is to split the string into characters and use a lookup table for replacements:

```
locals {
  input = "(UTC+01:00) Paris, Bohn, Helsinki, Hungary,Sweden, Austria"

  input_chars = split("", local.input)

  translation = tomap({
    "+" = "_plus_"
    "(" = ""
    ")" = ""
    "&" = "and"
    "." = ""
    "'" = "-"
    "," = "_"
    ":" = "_"
    " " = "_"
  })

  output_tokens = tolist([
    for c in local.input_chars : try(local.translation[c], c)
  ])

  output = lower(join("", local.output_tokens))
}

output "input_chars" {
  value = local.input_chars
}

output "output_tokens" {
  value = local.output_tokens
}

output "output" {
  value = local.output
}
```

I included output values for `input_chars` and `output_tokens` just so you can easily look at the intermediate steps if you like, but the main thing here is the output value `output`, whose value is the following:

```
output = "utc_plus_01_00_paris__bohn__helsinki__hungary_sweden__austria"
```

Your example output seems to have all of the sequences of more than one `_` reduced to a single underscore, and it isn't clear to me how your original example in Jinja was achieving that, but if that's important to your result then you could use a *single* `replace` call to achieve that final cleanup, leading to the following addition:

```
  output_consolidate = replace(local.output, "/([_-])+/", "$1")
```

Which produces the following result, by replacing any sequence of one or more underscores or dashes with a single underscore or dash:

```
output_consolidate = "utc_plus_01_00_paris_bohn_helsinki_hungary_sweden_austria"
```